# php, admin and user login from same browser causing session variable to be changed unwantedly

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

Both admin and users can log in. After logging in they can browse same pages.

There are options for admin and users to insert, edit and delete items.

Admin can do all those 3 tasks for any items created by anyone. But a user can perform those tasks only  for the items created by him/herself. So tracking is there in database AS TO  who created a particular item.

`$_SESSION['admin_user']` is assigned 1 if it is the admin or 2 otherwise. This session variable decides whether the page is intended for the admin or any other user.

But if the admin logs in and then another user also logs in from the same browser then the session variable gets the latter value.

For whatever reason, let use assume that such scenario for the admin and user to log into the same browser at the same time can take place.

How to make it possible that even if those two different type of users enter the site in the mentioned way, both of them will get their corresponding pages (i.e. when admin clicks on a menu link s/he will get the expected page and the same will be true for any user from the same browser at the same time)?

Comment: POST your code , how you assign value to session

Comment: So simple. if the login is from the admin login section, then `$_SESSION['admin_user']=1` and if it is from the user login section , then the session variable is assigned 2.

Comment: From what I understand you're assigning a different value to the same variable, you probably should have two variables : $_SESSION['is_admin'] = 1, $_SESSION['is_user'] = 1

Comment: The session is always shared in a browser. Without that you can not browse to a new page and still be logged in. The only way to solve it would be to make it a single page ajax site so it's not reloaded (and not rely on sessions). Or that you teach the users what "Incognito mode" is.

Comment: @jeromesmadja, when both both admin and user log in, which session variable should be used ? ` $_SESSION['is_admin'] ` or `$_SESSION['is_user']` ?

Comment: @Nils, even if it a single page ajax site, then it may be necessary to refresh the page after the other login.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed always the one that has the more privileges

Comment: @jeromesmadja, what do you mean by 'more privileges' ? admin and user have their own full privileges.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed The admin can do anything that a user can do, I'm actually not sure if that's the case here.

Comment: ready to explain any obscurity, please

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: see my answer bellow. The most important is to always send the session in your request and not relay on cookies.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**$_SESSION['admin_user'] is assigned 1 if it is the admin or 2 otherwise. This session variable decides whether the page is intended for the admin or any other user.**

```
if ($_SESSION['user']==1){

echo 'wHAT ADMIN CAN DO normally all even delete'; 

}else if($_SESSION['user']==2){

echo 'Maybe only add , view , update'; 

}
```

Be sure to make a redirect header to restrict non-user into the page

Comment: how many admin and users on your page , do your customer have unique id?

Comment: You have to learn more about login system with privileged,
normally theres two different session we will store 1 for admin 1 for customer , and the value is normally their unique id

Comment: looking for an answer, please.

Comment: Set your own rule into your system , disallow them to login both , do you really want to show login panel for user that already loged in?

Comment: the question is about allowing both of them.`show login panel for user that already loged in`- what do you mean please ?

Comment: what about separate them into two different session? so they don't overwrite each other

Comment: see my disussion with jeromesmadja beneath my post please.

Answer (score 0):

If your users use one and the same browser then you can nor relay on the normal session function as it's shared in the browser. That's why you can open new window/tab, a for instance.

So we can't use cookies to create the session, instead we need to send the session information with every request in the URL.

Option 1: Make it a single page web site and load data with ajax.

Option 2: Include session id in the users URL:s

Edit: An easier option would be to get your users to use Incognito mode. Then the sessions is not shared with other instances. I use that to login twice on different gmail accounts sometimes. (Different browser vendors call the function with their own name)

Edit2: First, the session is created by the server setting a cookie in the browser. That cookie just contains a "random" string. That string can correspond to a file on the server (most common) or a row in a database (practical if you have several web servers with a load balancer in front of them. If another user where to guess this random string he would get access to the users session (this is also known as session hijacking).

Instead of storing the session in a cookie you can make keep it in the URL like `http://www.example.com/?sess_id=jdR3Tfs`. You can build this logic quite easily by your self, but in most web frameworks there are helpers to do this, in PHP for instance

Set in php.ini

```
session.use_cookies=0
session.use_trans_sid=1
```

Sometimes it's needed to grab the session id manually in the arrangement above, if I remember correctly it should look like this:

```
session_id($_GET['sessionid']);
session_start();
```

or

```
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

To be sure you could just do `print_r($_GET)` or visually look at the URL this is created.

Otherwise you can do it more manually

```
<?php
// testpage.php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['test']){
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'Back again!';
}
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello world!';
?>
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['test']; ?></p> 
<a href="testpage.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>">Click me</a>.
```

Edit 3: 
ANother way, when you still can use cookies is that your users enable "private browsing", see more information on how to enable here http://techlogon.com/2012/05/10/comparison-of-private-browsing-in-ie-chrome-and-firefox/

Comment: suppose the request variable in the url is `user_type`; Now a user logs in first, so the variable gets the value 2, now the admin logs in with the same browser, so the variable gets the value 1; Now the user refreshes the page and clicks on a link to go to a different page. The request variable will hold the value 1 instead of 2.

Comment: No, forget about $session it will not work. You need session_id=(long random string) in the URL. That is saved in a database with a timestamp to calculate session timeouts. In that table you can save other info regarding the session.

Comment: Your idea with user_type would work but it would be silly as the user could switch between admin and user without authentication. On server side you would read user_type and return a page for that user type and also making sure all links include the correct user type. DON'T DO THIS! Use session id in the URL if security is a concern.

Comment: can you please modify your answer so that i can have a better understanding ?

Comment: the `sess_id` url parameter determines whether it is the admin or a user browsing the page, right? If yes, then after a user logs in, if the admin logs in, and then the user refreshes the page, how to determine who has logged in the user page? Won't the user be treated as the admin then ? Even if 2 session variables are used for  tracking purpose , which variable will start working ?

Comment: The session id identify one single unique user. It will work with two different sessions in the same browser as long you have the session in the URL. Just save user type in the session variable, $_SESSION['group'] = 'user'. This will work as long as your users don't take the wrong browser window. PS. Don't forget to remove your old cookies before you test this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19667/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-nils)

Comment: recommending the user to use an incognito window is not any good option i think. it would help me if I would get the answers to the questions in my last comment.